# Excel VBA Cut & paste active row on an active sheet,active row to first blank row on another worksheet

Tags: excel, paste, cut

I can copy and paste from an active sheet and active row to an "Activesheet_Archivesheet" on the next blank line but if I try and cut and paste I cannot find the code to find the next blank line and "paste".
Any pointers please? (ie if I have missed a previous post).

Excel VBA

Comment: If an answer helped you, then please mark it as correct.

Answer (score 0):

For column A, this selects the next empty row and ignores blanks in the data set.
As you see, it gets the empty row from the bottom.

```
Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Select
```